# Django - submit button value

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to send the value of a button when a form is submitted using the POST method.

```
    {% block content %}
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <form action="" method="post" id="news-create" class="form">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add News</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {{ form }}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="save_new" value="Save as new" />
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </form>
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
<script>
    var form_options = { target: '#modal', success: function(response) {} };
    $('#news-create').ajaxForm(form_options);
</script>

{% endblock content %}
```

But when I print the QueryDict request.POST inside the file view.py the value of the button is not present.

How can I get the value? I need to perform different action based on the button clicked.

At the moment I'm  using a bootstrap modal view to render a form (UpdateView) based on a model.

Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

To send the value of the submit button the name attribute of that button should be "submit".

So try it like this:

```
 <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
 <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save as new" />
```

Then you can do `request.POST.get('submit')` on your views to get the value of the button which was clicked.

You can also use checkbox for this kinds of things.